# Do I need to cross my Tx and Rx for an Ethernet AUI interface device?

Tags: ethernet

I have one device with an AUI Ethernet interface coming out of a non-standard connector. I'm making a cable to attach the device to a COTS transceiver which contains the standard D-Type AUI connector. On the non-tranceiver device documentation, it has pins labeled as "Tx+", "Tx-", "Rx+", "Rx-", etc. On the transceiver documentation, it just says "standard D-Type AUI connector" which I can readily find a pin-out for.

I'm a little confused on whether I need to cross the Tx and Rx lines in my cable. The standard AUI connector lists pin 3 and 10 as Data Out, and I think this is relative to the device that houses the connector (the transceiver).

Here is the installation manual for the transceiver: http://www.unicomlink.com/pdfs/20028T_Manual.pdf

It says I need a "transceiver drop cable." Any ideas what that means?

Answer (score 1):

The transceiver drop cable is more than likely an AUI cable that can be placed between the AUI connector of the Ethernet device (DA15 female) and the AUI connector of the transceiver (DA15 male). It is a simple 15-wire shielded straight cable. It is optional as the device and the transceiver can be connected directly (they have mating connectors).

If the interface on your Ethernet device has different pin names or a completely different number of pins from the [AUI standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attachment_Unit_Interface#Connector_and_signals) (no Tx+, Tx-, Rx+, Rx- should be there!), then it may be something completely different, and not an AUI.

If there are only 4 pins, labelled Tx+, Tx-, Rx+, Rx-, then it's likely a 10Base-T or 100Base-TX UTP interface (needs an RJ45 socket only, with or without isolating magnetics).